# How to compare two Timestamp In kusto

Tags: kql

I have one Timestamp column in Table and I want to compare that Timestamp value with ingestion_time()
For example:
Timestamp                   ingestion_time
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000     2021-01-01 00:20:10.000

So in this case I want to compare only date value like (1970-01-01!=2021-01-01) then set true

how to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `startofday()`, or `bin()`.

For example:

```
T
| extend result = startofday(Timestamp) != startofday(ingestion_time())
```